# pyserial can't find device using serial.tools.list_ports.grep()

Tags: python, windows, pyserial

I have a USB device (based on STM32F4 microcontroller) with VID, PID and Product Description setup in the USB descriptors.

```
VID = 0x0483
PID = 0x5740
Product Description = "ACME thing-a-me-bob"
```

On macOS, using `serial.tools.list_ports.grep()` works great to locate my device.  e.g. `p = grep("thing-a-me-bob")` or `p = grep("ACME")

However on Windows (Win 10), grep does not find my device.  If i use `grep("")` then it does list my device (along with all the others) but it just shows:

`COM3 - USB Serial Device (COM3)`

The device is just using the standard Microsoft CDC driver that comes with Win 10.  I would have thought however that simple/standard thinks like the product description string would be read from a a USB device and used (just like the standard macOS driver does).

Is there a way to get `serial.tools.list_ports.grep()` to work with standard windows drivers?

Note: `grep("0483:5740")` does find my device, however this a reasonably commonly used set of VID:PID values, provided by ST Micro.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `grep()` works but you can connect like this.

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    ports = list(list_ports.comports())
    for port in ports:
        # query each port and connect if description is found
        if 'ACME thing-a-me-bob' in port.description:
            s = serial.Serial(port.device)
```